# Can you transform a continuous probability space into an equiprobable probability space?

Tags: probability-theory

Can we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ where $\Omega$ is uncountable but $P$ is rational-valued (i.e., the range is a subset of $\mathbb Q$)?

Why I’m asking: I was considering transforming a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ into a ‘corresponding’ $(\Omega_2, \mathcal F_2, P_2)$ where each $\{\omega_2\}$ for $\omega_2 \in \Omega_2$ is equiprobable. When $P$ is rational-valued, I can find the GCD $G$, and stick $G \div P(\{\omega\})$ corresponding elements in $\Omega_2$ for every $\omega in \Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

No, the sum of uncountably many positive reals (and therefore also uncountably many positive rationals) is infinite. Therefore, unless your $P$ maps all but countably many $\{\omega\}$ to $0$ (not what you intended), $P$ cannot sum to the finite value of 1 as required to be a probability space.